# hide Post Author badge in comments

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using WordPress Customizr Theme, the Classical version. This theme seems to create a blue "Post Author" badge in comments. I found this, but solutions don’t seem to work:

https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/remove-post-meta-details/

I also tried this…

```
.comment-meta cite.fn {
    display: none; !important;
}
```

…but it also hides the Author’s name (which I don’t want).

You can see example page here:

https://www.lifeleap.org/psychic-project/target-1a-discussion/

Any suggestions on how to just hide the "Post Author" badge in the comments? I was desperatly hoping to find a CSS solution instead of hacking the theme files.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS to hide only the badge:

```
.comment-meta cite.fn > span {
    display: none;
}
```

That badge is inside the `span` (the author name is not), so this selector will only hide the span, i.e. the badge